# Laravel validator escaping database name

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have table that has a "." sign in it's name, it's called 'database.com'. I am using the validator to validate the inputs on signup on my site. This is the laravel code

```
$validator = Validator::make($params,
            array(
                "username" => "required|unique:database.com.users,name",
                "email" => "required|email|unique:database.com.users,mail",
                'password' => 'required|min:6',
                'password-confirmation' => 'required|same:password'
            )
        );
```

This produces a laravel error

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`users` where `name` = ?' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `'database`.`com'`.`users` where `name` = dfgdf)","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\mobile\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php","line":555}}
```

I think the problem is the '.' sign in the database name, but I can`t escape it properly, if I put the db name like this

```
"username" => "required|unique:'database.com'.users,name",
```

the validation does not work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to make the laravel validator work with a database that has a '.' in the name. If I escape the db name validator does not work.

Comment: I am asking about what validation rule are you implementing

Comment: I need the username and email to be unique. And the database where we are storing usernames and emails is not the same database that app is configured to. That is why I need to reference the database name directly in the validator array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Laravel's unique validation rule supports that syntax. You can always create your own custom rules easily (thank you Taylor!)
[Laravel custom validation rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)